# Page Controller with Navigation Controller issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard

My Page Controller handles transition of 3 view Controllers but to jump in the first of these 3 view Controllers, I use a Navigation Controller with a push segue to Page View Controller (RootViewController in storyboard). I post links to images because i can't upload image directly (i havent't enough reputation).

Storyboard:
[Storyboard](http://oi58.tinypic.com/8wfnub.jpg)

This is the effect obtained: a black bar over the view.
But when I touch the view, it position itself correctly.
[EffectBeforeTouch and EffectAfterTouch](http://oi61.tinypic.com/2hf54c4.jpg)

I can't see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In storyboard, try to deselect "Adjust Scroll View Insets" on the PageViewController. Or do it programmatically

```
myPageViewController.automaticallyAdjustScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Comment: it works, but i can't understand why i need to do that if i haven't a scrollview.